# Increase or decrease Kafka partitions dynamically

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have a system where load is not constant. We may get 1000 requests a day or no requests at all.

We use Kafka to pass on the requests between services. We have kept average number of Kafka consumers to reduce cost incurred. Now my consumers of Kafka will sit ideal if there are no requests received that day, and there will be lag if too many requests are received.

We want to keep these consumers on Autoscale mode, such that my number of servers(Kafka consumer) will increase if there is a spike in number of requests. Once the number of requests get reduced, we will remove the servers. Therefore, the Kafka partitions have to be increased or decreased accordingly

1. Kafka allows increasing partition. In this case, how can we decrease Kafka partitions dynamically?
2. Is there any other solution to handle this Auto-scaling?

Comment: You cannot decrease partitions

Answer (score 5):

Scaling up partitions will not fix your lag problems in the short term since no data is moved between partitions when you do this, so existing (or new) consumers are still stuck with reading the data in the previous partitions.

It's not possible to decrease partitions and its not possible to scale consumers beyond the partition count.

If you are able to sacrifice processing order for consumption speed, you can separate the consuming threads and working threads, as hinted at in the KafkaConsumer javadoc, then you would be able to scale these worker threads.
Since you are thinking about modifying the partition counts, then I'm guessing processing order isn't a problem.

> have one or more consumer threads that do all data consumption and hands off ConsumerRecords instances to a blocking queue consumed by a pool of processor threads that actually handle the record processing.

Answer (score 2):

A single consumer can consume multiple partitions. Therefore partition your work for the largest anticipated parallel requirement, and then scale your number of consumers as required.

For example, if you think you need 32 parallel consumers you would give you Kafka topic 32 partitions.

You can run 32 consumers (each gets one partition), or eight consumers (each gets four partitions) or just one (which gets all 32 partitions). Or any number of consumers in between. Kafka's protocol ensures that within the consumer group all partitions are consumed, and will rebalance as and when consumers are added or removed.